# How can I return a list of summary statistics?

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I'm writing a function whose output is a list of summary statistics for a data frame of unknown columns. For example, if my data frame had 3 columns, my list output needs to be as such:

```
col1  
col1mean  
(mean of column 1)  

col1
col1median  
(median of column 1)

col2  
col2$mean  
(mean of column 2)

col2  
col2$median  
(median of column2)  

col3  
col3mean  
(mean of column 3)  

col3  
col3median  
(median of column 3)
```

My question is, how can I return my list so that it will cycle through mean, median, and standard deviation for n number of columns?

Comment: How does the current list not meet your needs? How exactly are you planning to "cycle" thought this list and how do you plan to use those values? It's not clear to me what the problem is. If would be helpful to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with actual runnable code and sample data to recreate your exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach with `lapply`:

```
# example data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(10), col2 = rnorm(10), col3 = rnorm(10))

lapply(dat, function(x) list(mean = mean(x), median = median(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

The result:

```
$col1
$col1$mean
[1] 0.07462564

$col1$median
[1] -0.07983455

$col1$sd
[1] 0.9537841


$col2
$col2$mean
[1] 0.208622

$col2$median
[1] 0.3802926

$col2$sd
[1] 1.038073


$col3
$col3$mean
[1] -0.4245589

$col3$median
[1] -0.6769652

$col3$sd
[1] 0.9308092
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had this before:

x<- sapply(x,mean)
y<- sapply(x,median)
z<- sapply(x,sd)

list(x[1],y[1],z[1]) 

but didnt know how to generalize it for any number of columns.

Comment: Also, just a quick question so I can understand it better, but what  purpose does "function(x)" serve?

Comment: @Mole The function introduced by `function(x)` (i.e., `list...`) is applied to all columns. Here, `x` represents a column.

Answer (score 2):

I have a function for when I do work like this. `easyStats()` calculates the mean, median, standard deviation, maximum, and minimum for a vector.  You can use it easily with `lapply()`, and might produce a more desirable result than what you show. Here's an example on the first three columns of `mtcars`.  If there are NA values, you can also add `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
lapply(mtcars[1:3], easyStats)
# $mpg
#   mean median     sd    max    min 
# 20.091 19.200  6.027 33.900 10.400 
#
# $cyl
#   mean median     sd    max    min 
#  6.188  6.000  1.786  8.000  4.000 
#
# $disp
#    mean  median      sd     max     min 
# 230.722 196.300 123.939 472.000  71.100
```

`easyStats` is defined as

```
easyStats <- function (x, digits = 3L, ...) {
    stopifnot(as.logical(length(x)), is.vector(x), is.numeric(x))
    funs <- c("mean", "median", "sd", "max", "min")
    mp <- mapply(function(f, ...) match.fun(f)(x, ...), funs, ...)
    round(mp, digits = digits)
}
```

But for your particular problem, you could adjust the function to

```
easyStats2 <- function(x, funs = c("mean", "median", "sd"), digits = 3L, ...) {
    mp <- mapply(function(f, ...) match.fun(f)(x, ...), funs, ...)
    round(mp, digits = digits)
}
```

and then call

```
lapply(mtcars[1:3], function(x) as.list(easyStats2(x)))
```

Comment: You should make `funs` a parameter with default values.